# Permalink structure by Post Meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, meta-value, customization

I have the following issue:

Two Custom Post Types, lets call them **cpt1** and **cpt2**.

In **cpt2**, I have a custom meta box in which you can select a post from **cpt1**, its `post ID` is stored in a meta value called `postid`.

The permalink structure of **cpt2** is `/%post_type%/%post_name%/`.

What i'm trying to accomplish is:

1. When `postid` has a `post ID` of **cpt1** (wich will always be the case since it is a required field), the permalink structure of that specific post will become `/selected_post_slug/%post_type%/%post_name%/`.
2. The **cpt2** archive page must be available by `/selected_post_slug/cpt2/`, so it looks like every **cpt1** page has its own **cpt2** archive.

I managed to get point 1 to work by adding the following code in my `functions.php` file:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%selected_meta%', '([^&]+)', '?meta=' );

function extra_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( stripos( $permalink, '%selected_meta%' ) == false )
        return $permalink;

    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'ervaring' ) {
        $_selected_post_slug = '';
        $_selected_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rating-post', true );

        if ( $_selected_post_id )
            $_selected_post_slug = get_page_uri( $_selected_post_id );

        if ( ! $_selected_post_slug )
            return str_replace( '%selected_meta%', '', $permalink );

        return str_replace( '%selected_meta%', "$_selected_post_slug/", $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'extra_post_link', 10, 3 );
```

I followed a quick tutorial about [adding rewrite tags in the permalink structure](http://xplus3.net/2010/10/04/wp-rewrite-tags-in-permalinks/) wich showed me how to figure out the first thing.

But, unfortunately, I'm still working on a solution for point 2.

Could I get some thought about this issue to help me a bit further down the road? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this line:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%selected_meta%', '([^&]+)', '?meta=' );
```

Into:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%selected_meta%', '([^&]+)', 'post_type=ervaring&meta=' );
```

Wich was for both issue 1 and 2 enough to work with.

Comment: thanks mate - helpfull that you to supplied your solution